# Upload request ignored by spring boot server

Tags: java, file, file-upload, multipart

I have a class as such that should upload files to amazon s3 But i am not able to hit the endpoint. I am using postman when i perform http://localhost:8088/api/user/all it works fine . But uploading returns 401 unauthorized. I try to debug but my request does not even enter the controller

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api")
    @RestController
    public class PostController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

        @Autowired
        private PhotoService photoService;

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/upload")
        public Photo submitPhoto(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
            LOGGER.debug("submitPhoto({})", file);
           return photoService.savePhoto(file);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/user/all")
        public List<User> loadAll() {
            return this.userService.findAll();
        }
}
```

So i found on SO how to upload file with POSTMAN i have used their examples but thesame result, I cant even debug because request is not hitting the method as if my url is wrong.

THis is my request to postman 
http://localhost:8088/api/upload
also Using Form-data name key=ile and choosing a file from my pc, I have tried both with selecting headers and no headers, I have also used both RequestPart and RequestBody in my controller.

Any suggestions Please ?

At somepoint i am getting in my enviroment(Intellij)

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Character decoding failed. Parameter [���� JFIF      �� �Photoshop 3.0 8BIM     g( bFBMD01000aa80300001424000049540000a05600008b590000827a0000cbc30000eacb00004cd100007cd700003b640100 ��ICC_PROFILE   lcms  mntrRGB XYZ �    ) 9acspAPPL                          ��     �-lcms                                               
desc   �   ^cprt  \   wtpt  h   bkpt  |   rXYZ  �   gXYZ  �   bXYZ  �   rTRC  �   @gTRC  �   @bTRC  �   @desc       c2                                                                                  text    FB  XYZ       ��     �-XYZ         3  �XYZ       o�  8�  �XYZ       b�  ��  �XYZ       $�  �  ��curv          ��ck�?Q4!�)�2;�FQw]�kpz���|�i�}���0���� C 
db° §jÊ¼@9H<HY-²£W
âyÃèaæÛÒÉ<ÚzhY}SDúØydôâ<¹ôêe½<úú5<ôÝSl,iC:v¢s ¢ÄªÊ!y®²öãÖy:V·¬s®sé!ÒÜ/Dç5ÐjÂ¶(,°ñ ñ"±B<®Jál®ZÑ`íYVÁ)ÂÊ°,$)Ö L³Z²"0)ÊÉcTKeL;Ó$è~Xu
é«2Ól©³6.Äî^] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
 Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a content type that's appropriate for binary data. `application/octet-stream` is one option.
You can also change your code to use `@RequestParam("file")` instead of `@RequestPart`. Then use form data in body with `"file"` as key.

Comment: I tried binary data  Content-Type- application/octet-stream but i get 401 so i am still using form-data since most example use that , just mine doesnt work for some reason

Comment: You are getting an org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Character decoding failed. exception right?

Comment: But when i use form-data i get no exception just 401

Comment: you should use application/octet-stream . Can you please share your request headers?

Comment: Yes this is it X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma →no-cache
Expires →0
X-Frame-Options →DENY
Content-Length →0
Date →Sun, 23 Jun 2019 17:53:19 GMT

Comment: Ok. Can you please try one thing. Don't set any content type in headers.Also change your code to use @RequestParam("file") instead of @RequestPart . Then in postman use form data in body with "file" as key

Comment: @PostMapping("/upload")
    @ResponseBody
    public Photo submitPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("submitPhoto({})", file);
         return photoService.savePhoto(file);
    }

Comment: With no Headers and i still get 401